# Image Upload Crash in Firebase Codelabs FriendlyChat Tutorial

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Running through the codelabs Firebase tutorial covering FriendlyChat. Addressed constant issue (answered elsewhere) but when I go to upload the selected image, my app crashes. I redid all steps and tested the "complete" version of the tutorial source code to ensure it wasn't something I was doing. No luck. Anyone else seeing this issue?

Here is the exception...

2016-05-23 17:25:13.119 FriendlyChatSwift[61549:15581893] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (6), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

When I check the message count on initial load, it's fine. When I go to the imagePicker and come back, suddenly message count is 1 but the row count is still 6.

The problem appears to be here:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.messages.removeAll()
    // Listen for new messages in the Firebase database
    _refHandle = self.ref.child("messages").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
        self.messages.append(snapshot)
        self.clientTable.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: self.messages.count-1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

    })
}
```

If you remove all the messages then the index is off in the call to insertRowsAtIndexPaths.

Comment: Would you mind uploading the exception or error message being thrown so we have something to work with?

Comment: Apologies, Mike. Exception added...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I got this to work by moving all the code from viewWillAppear to the end of viewDidLoad. Because viewWillAppear is called every time the view shows up again, it ends up being called after you get out of the photos view and return back to the table view. viewDidLoad, on the other hand, is only called once, at the beginning when the view is loaded. It works also when the user goes back to the home screen and returns to the app.</strike>

Figured out the real solution. The discussion on this [twitter thread](https://twitter.com/NatashaTheRobot/status/511501523709218817) explains what you have to do and why. The code firebase provides should go in viewDidAppear, as they had. However, you need to reload your table after you removeAll messages.

```
self.messages.removeAll()
self.clientTable.reloadData()
```

And then your viewWillDisappear needs to correctly remove the observer, as outlined by Ibrahim Ulukaya above.

```
self.ref.child("messages").removeObserverWithHandle(_refHandle)
```

The reason it should be in viewDidAppear is so you can re-start observing the table when the view comes back to the top. And the observer needs to be removed in viewWillDisappear so that you do not have a view responding to an observer/notification when it is not on screen as this violates the MVC rules.

Hope this helps. I struggled with this for a while. Not sure how the Firebase team didn't catch this.

Answer (score 0):

The main error was that in viewWillDisappear removed the observer in wrong reference.
It should be

```
self.ref.child("messages").removeObserverWithHandle(_refHandle)
```

instead. Also you'd like to reloadData after removeAll in your viewWillAppear.

You wouldn't need to removeobjects and reloaddata everytime if you move them to viewDidLoad and deAlloc.

(I'll be updating the sourcecode shortly.)